# nodejs add line number to winston based logger

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, winston

How can I add line number to this following winston-based logger?
So that the line number appears at the end of the file path.

```
const winston = require('winston');

winston.emitErrs = true;
const logger = function (module) {
    let parts, path;
    parts = module.filename.split('\\');
    path = parts[parts.length - 2] + '\\' + parts.pop();
    return new winston.Logger({
        transports: [
            new winston.transports.Console({
                level: 'debug',
                handleExceptions: true,
                json: false,
                colorize: true,
                label: path,
                timestamp: true
            })
        ],
        exitOnError: false
    });
};
module.exports = logger;
```

### update

current output example is like:
`2018-06-10T00:13:33.344Z - info: [app\main.js] Here is my log`

the desired format is: 
`2018-06-10T00:13:33.344Z - info: [app\main.js:150] Here is my log` 
in which 150 is appended to the file path.

Comment: Line number for what? How many times a log message has been printed? What would be the purpose for such a thing? If you mean something else specific, then you had best state that in your question.

Comment: Why would a line number from the source be included in the log message unless you supplied that yourself? The logger does not "parse" your source files, it just emits data. The only time you are likely to see a line number you do not supply is within an error stack trace.

Comment: Seems like a very simple and valid question. A logger should be able to provide the line number, and most that I have dealt with in the past do.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code in a new file `winston.js`. and the Use it by requiring it anywhere.

```
var winston = require('winston')
var path = require('path')
var PROJECT_ROOT = path.join(__dirname, '..')
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');


const options = {
  file: {
    level: 'info',
    filename: `${appRoot}/logs/app.log`,
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: true,
    maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
    maxFiles: 5,
    colorize: false,
    timestamp: true
  },
  console: {
    level: 'debug',
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: true,
    colorize: true,
    timestamp: true
  }
};

var logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File(options.file),
    new winston.transports.Console(options.console)
  ],
  exitOnError: false // do not exit on handled exceptions
});

logger.stream = {
  write: function (message) {
    logger.info(message)
  }
}

// A custom logger interface that wraps winston, making it easy to instrument
// code and still possible to replace winston in the future.

module.exports.debug = module.exports.log = function () {
  logger.debug.apply(logger, formatLogArguments(arguments))
}

module.exports.info = function () {
  logger.info.apply(logger, formatLogArguments(arguments))
}

module.exports.warn = function () {
  logger.warn.apply(logger, formatLogArguments(arguments))
}

module.exports.error = function () {
  logger.error.apply(logger, formatLogArguments(arguments))
}

module.exports.stream = logger.stream

/**
 * Attempts to add file and line number info to the given log arguments.
 */
function formatLogArguments (args) {
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(args)

  var stackInfo = getStackInfo(1)

  if (stackInfo) {
    // get file path relative to project root
    var calleeStr = '(' + stackInfo.relativePath + ':' + stackInfo.line + ')'

    if (typeof (args[0]) === 'string') {
      args[0] = calleeStr + ' ' + args[0]
    } else {
      args.unshift(calleeStr)
    }
  }

  return args
}

/**
 * Parses and returns info about the call stack at the given index.
 */
function getStackInfo (stackIndex) {
  // get call stack, and analyze it
  // get all file, method, and line numbers
  var stacklist = (new Error()).stack.split('\n').slice(3)

  // stack trace format:
  // http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi
  // do not remove the regex expresses to outside of this method (due to a BUG in node.js)
  var stackReg = /at\s+(.*)\s+\((.*):(\d*):(\d*)\)/gi
  var stackReg2 = /at\s+()(.*):(\d*):(\d*)/gi

  var s = stacklist[stackIndex] || stacklist[0]
  var sp = stackReg.exec(s) || stackReg2.exec(s)

  if (sp && sp.length === 5) {
    return {
      method: sp[1],
      relativePath: path.relative(PROJECT_ROOT, sp[2]),
      line: sp[3],
      pos: sp[4],
      file: path.basename(sp[2]),
      stack: stacklist.join('\n')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this include the line number?